# User script or other way to hide the reputation section of the user profile page?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Anybody know a method of editing the user profile page, in particular to allow user to remove the **reputation** this week, bar graph etc. section on the right-hand side of the page?

This would **NOT** be a global change, simply one that allows each user to decide to retain or delete this feature.

Personally I would rather know more about the questions I asked or the answers that I gave than be distracted by that section.

The answer is probably no, but I was wondering, could it be deleted if the user wanted to?

Comment: But what for? Is it shame to have low rep or not to be a top user? I don't think so.......

Comment: Hi    I suppose it depends on the individual user, I would rather know more about the questions I asked or the answers that I gave than be distracted by that section.  It's just up to the personality of the user, I guess... anyway thanks and best regards

Comment: @rene     no, no way for  everyone, just for those users who, as I said in the question, would rather not use that part of the page  thanks and best regards

Comment: @rene  I understand and accept fully the motivation behind your earlier comments.  They were perfectly valid questions. . Could you please just confirm before I make any changes that this will only affect my profile  page **only** .  I do fully accept how important the reputation system is and if there is the slightest chance of affecting any other page I will leave it just as it is. Thanks very much for your help regards

Comment: @irishphysics I've added that to my answer and you're correct. This only affects how YOU see user profiles. Other users will see everything no matter what you blocked with Stylish. It is an client-side tool/trick only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find that information distracting you can remove it for you if you use [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and add this rule:

```
div#user-panel-reputation 
{
  display:none;
}
```

And gone is the graph and reputation summary...

[image]

Without adding an *applies to* setting in stylish this works for all user profiles. If you want to only apply it on certain sites add an apply to rule:

[image: applies to rule in Stylish]

If you only want the style to be active on your own profile but not on others you would add the url `http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/286701`.

And to be clear: this only impacts how you see the user profiles. Other users get to see the full view no matter what **YOU** block with this client-side tool.

Comment: Hi as I said in my comments above, I personally do find it distracting being given a week by week summary. I can't elaborate more than that because that **is** the reason. It's simply based on the personal  preferences of each user. Thanks  for the answer tho, regards